# Android APIs and CPU Architectures

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm building my native components from the command line (and *not* from `Android.mk`). I'm trying to determine the intersection of CPU architectures with API levels. I know:

- `armeabi` is ARMv5TE
- `armeabi-v7a` is ARMv7-A

I'm trying to determine the minimum API level required for `armeabi` (ARMv5TE) and `armeabi-v7a` (ARMv7-A). I need the minimum API level to select the proper `sysroot`. For example, I can select:

- `/opt/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-19/arch-arm`

or

- `/opt/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-9/arch-arm`

What are the intersections of API levels with `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a`?

---

According to the NDK's `docs/CPU-MIPS.html` and `CPU-X86.html`, MIPS and X86 minimum API level is 9. But I can't find a similar document for ARM.

---

According to the NDK's `docs/NEON.html`, ARMv7-a made its debut in NDK R3 which is dated March 2010. That puts ARMv7-a around API 8 from May 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARM has been supported since the first releases (release 3 is the first one to support native NDK development at all). Since both `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` link to the same libraries (in the `arch-arm` subdirectory), both of them are supported since release 3.

To find this out for yourself, just look in `<NDK>/platforms/android-X` for the lowest value of X where `arch-arm` (or similarly, `arch-x86` and `arch-mips`) exists.

In general, there's no risk or harm in having newer architecture code in an APK running on an older device - the older device just won't look at the unknown architectures. The only risk is in the NDK build failing since the `arch-X` directory is missing if building for a too old platform version, in which case you can fix it yourself immediately by targeting a newer platform version.

Comment: So I'm clear... [ARMv7-a is a Cortex-A5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_microarchitectures). The Cortex A5 was [released in 2011](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2009/10/arm-fills-out-cpu-lineup-with-cortex-a5/). I think that means `armeabi-v7a` would have debuted around API 10 or 11. [API 3 is from 2009](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history), and it predates ARMv7-a by two or three years. So that would mean Android's `armeabi-v7a` gear is really just `armeabi`?

Comment: What I would really like to do is disassemble the libraries and look at each instruction, and see what instruction set its in. I suspect (but don't know) that `armeabi-v7a` is *not* using the SIMD instructions. That would probably take hand tuned assembly language routines...

Comment: ARMv7-a isn't necessarily Cortex-A5, and those cores weren't released in numerical order. The first one probably was Cortex-A8, and those were available in consumer devices already in 2009. The first actual android devices that ran on ARMv7 chips were released with Android 2.0 I think (probably Motorola Droid or so). If you build an APK which contains both an `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` library targeting android-3, it will run just fine on an Android 1.5 device, it will just ignore the `armeabi-v7a` version.

Comment: Also, as I said, both `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` builds both link to the same libraries in `arch-arm` - they are binary compatible. What actual instruction sets a device supports or uses is pretty much independent from the actual API level (except that there are no officially supported x86 or MIPS devices before API level 9 - prior unofficial builds did exist, but they aren't necessarily compatible with the official standard).

Comment: When you build targeting `armeabi-v7a` it will use much more efficient instructions than when targeting `armeabi` - in particular, it will actually use the FPU, while `armeabi` builds only will use softfloat. Neither of them will use any SIMD instructions though, since not all `armeabi-v7a` devices do have the NEON SIMD instructions (in particular, Tegra 2 lacks them).

Comment: To use NEON instructions, you'll have to enable extra compiler options (and normally the compiler won't emit many such instructions anyway, the autovectorizer seldom does anything) or write such instructions in assembly. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/532389e89c/docs/text/CPU-ARM-NEON.text for more details on this.

Comment: Thanks for all the help mstorsjo. I've read the various CPU docs in the DK and thought I had a good understanding, but I see I was wrong.